# CodeIgniter: Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly...using HTTPS

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl

I'm working with a website that I didn't build, that uses CodeIgniter as its framework. I had a relatively simple task: secure the site with an SSL certificate. No problem.

Except, the site will not load with HTTPS, although it still loads correctly using HTTP. It gives the following error with HTTPS:

> Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

Now, the error message seems self explanatory...change the system path in the index.php file, but this is what the system path is set to in that file:

```
$system_path = '/codeigniter/2_1_3';
```

Fine, but this folder doesn't exist in the directory structure, and neither does a folder named 'system.'

So, I really don't have a clue how to fix this problem. It isn't even clear to me how the website functions at all since I can't find the folder it is supposed to be using as its system folder.

Any help would be appreciated. Please ask if there is any additional information you need to help.

Comment: Check the apache (or whatever web server you're using) vhost config.  It probably has an alias for `/codeigniter` pointing it to a real folder.  My guess is that alias only exists in the port 80 (http) vhost, not the port 443 (https) one.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I contacted our server admin and mentioned your suggestion and it solved the problem.

Comment: Awesome!  I figured that's what the issue was.  Only thing that made sense to me.  Glad you got it working.